# Windows 7 Update freezes - what to do?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Yesterday I shutdown my notebook, and Windows 7 Ultimate started to install automatic updates. After one hour, I noticed that the update was still running. I thought OK, I shall go to sleep and let it run. In the morning it was still running.

Thus, I thought it had crashed, forced a shutdown of the notebook and then restarted it. With the same effect that the notebook is "freezing" at "Install Update 1 of 5".

It does not look like it has crashed. The progress wheel is still moving. But it does not make any progress...

Would appreciate any help!

**Edit:**
OK, I was able to log-in into safe mode. This way I passed the install update screen. I do not want to generally disable updates, what can I do to not install the last update, which is creating troube. Or how can I find out whats the problem with the last update?

Comment: Tom, you should make the last Edit an answer and mark it as accepted. This way people looking for a solution will find it easier. Also it will limit the number of open unanswered questions on this site.

Comment: SU forces me to wait two days to accept my answer to my question. But you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in safe mode and installing the updates manually has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try and force and shut down and install the updates while the computer is running as opposed to doing it before/during shut down.

Comment: Actually would be nice. But I can not pass the install update screen. Is there a way to log-in without installing the updates, when w7 already begun to install them?